# Grab GET ajax calls from page just by providing URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here's an example of a page from the API I'm working with:
http://www.easports.com/fifa/football-club/apps/proclubs/PS4/CHIP%20IT%20BRO

On this page almost all of the data is being loaded in via GET calls.

Here are 3 of the main calls that I'm interested in:

http://www.easports.com/iframe/fifa14proclubs/api/platforms/PS4/clubs/66232/members

http://www.easports.com/iframe/fifa14proclubs/api/platforms/PS4/clubs/66232/info

http://www.easports.com/iframe/fifa14proclubs/api/platforms/PS4/clubs/66232/stats

You'll notice that there is one thing in common with these calls, and that is the number after the "clubs/" part of the URL. In this case, it's **66232**. That is the ID of the club. Basically, if I have this ID, I can get all of the information I need from this API.

*The problem:*

The only way I can grab this ID is if I manually inspect the page myself via Firebug. On my website, users will need to be able to automatically register their clubs. I want them to be able to provide the URL to their club page, eg.:
http://www.easports.com/fifa/football-club/apps/proclubs/PS4/CHIP%20IT%20BRO

Is there any way I can grab the ID in these ajax calls just by having the URL of the page? I don't even need the info that is returned from these calls, I just need the club ID that is part of the URL of these calls, eg.:

www.easports.com/iframe/fifa14proclubs/api/platforms/PS4/clubs/**66232**/members

I can just use some string functions to grab the ID after the "clubs/" substring up until the next "/".

I've been looking all over for a solution but can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance. :)

**EDIT:**

Why is my question getting downvoted like crazy? I think I explained it pretty well. :/

Answer (score 1):

Try using PHP's `DOMDocument`:

```
// clubId.php
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument; @$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.easports.com/fifa/football-club/apps/proclubs/PS4/CHIP IT BRO');
$bod = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body'); 
if($bod = $bod->item(0)){
  $cid = $bod->getAttribute('club-id');
  $ea = 'http://www.easports.com/iframe/fifa14proclubs/api/platforms/PS4/clubs/'.$cid;
  $members = @file_get_contents("$ea/memebers");
  $info = @file_get_contents("$ea/info");
  $stats = @file_get_contents("$ea/stats");
}
else{
  echo 'Sorry, the Page is Probably Blocked!';
}
?>
```

Now you can `echo $members`, and the like, into HTML that creates JavaScript. Of course, you should have a firm grasp on JavaScript Objects and Arrays.

IT DOES APPEAR BLOCKED THOUGH!!!

Comment: Recently web scraping has stopped working on any pages on EA's site. Every time I try to scrape something it says it's the HTML object is a non-object. I think they may have blocked it? For that reason I'm using YQL to access their JSON data, but I still can't seem to scrape anything off their HTML pages.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array in C:\Apache24\htdocs\register.php on line 6.

Comment: I then fixed that by adding "->item(0);" after "getElementsByTagName('body')" and I got this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object in C:\Apache24\htdocs\register.php on line 7

Comment: I can't even `@file_get_contents()` on the page. Do you really need to get the number off of this page?

Comment: It would automate the process of users registering their clubs. I've heard of other ways to do this such as using CORS but it looks really complicated.

Comment: If you have EA database access, why don't you query that to get the number, or the "CHIP IT BRO" part of the URL?

Comment: I don't really have access to the EA database, I'm just getting their JSON data. I need ways for casual users of my site to get the number. They'd just provide a link to their club page and my website would automatically do the rest. Unfortunately the only way to get the number is to use Firebug and get it myself.

Comment: I only know JavaScript and PHP. You could try using the JavaScript's FileReader API, although it won't work on some Browsers since it's so new. Sorry, I can't help any further.

Comment: Oh and by the way, why did this question get downvoted so much? :/

Comment: I didn't downvote you. I would guess it comes down to lack of relevant code. People want to know what you've tried.